# WebPack : How to get other js's values?

Tags: javascript, variables, webpack

I'm using [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/) 

THis is my code :

test.js :

```
var superText = "lol";
```

Main.js :

```
var test = require("./test.js");console.log(test.superText);
```

But it say me "test.superText is undefined" can i have acces of require's variables ? If yes how please ? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ploko](http://openclassrooms.com/membres/ploko-51243) on [OpenClassRoom](http://openclassrooms.com/) :
Il faut que tu le mettes dans les exports de ton module :

```js
module.exports = {
  superText: "lol"
};
 
 
var test = require("./test.js").superText;
```